# Python : How to create dictionary of unique words out of list of strings where words are mixed with symbols and numbers

Tags: python

Lets say I have 
list = ["1 I love , you / hey", "0 Because . you / are cute  ", ....]

I want to create a set of unique words, avoiding digits and symbols.
What would be the best way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Before we comment on "best" way, we should see that you have an attack on finding *some* way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want it to be case insensitive you can do:

```
lower_case_list = original_list.lower()
#convert from list of strings to one string
word_string = ' '.join(lower_case_list)
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
#get a list of characters that aren't letters
not_letters = [char_ for char_ in word_string if not in letters]
#get rid of characters that aren't letters
for not_letter in not_letters:
   word_string = word_string.replace(not_letter,"")
word_list = word_string.split(" ")
unique_word_set = set(word_list)
```

Note that this splits characters into different words if there are any spaces between them, for instance "Hello, how are you?" If you want to split even if there are no spaces, for instance "Hello,how are you?", you'll have to do  word_string.replace(not_letter," ") and then get rid of null strings.

Comment: I'm not allowed to write that you helped me with mine. So I won't.

Comment: Correction of one line: `not_letters = [char_ for char_ in word_string if char_ not in letters and char_ != ' ']` - otherwise the spaces are added to the not_letters and all the words get glued together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about 'best'. Here's one way.

```
>>> sentence = 'Glücklicherweise kann der Mensch nur einen gewissen Grad des Unglücks fassen; was darüber hinausgeht, vernichtet ihn oder läßt ihn gleichgültig.'
>>> import re
>>> sorted(set(re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', sentence).split()), key=str.lower)
['darüber', 'der', 'des', 'einen', 'fassen', 'gewissen', 'gleichgültig', 'Glücklicherweise', 'Grad', 'hinausgeht', 'ihn', 'kann', 'läßt', 'Mensch', 'nur', 'oder', 'Unglücks', 'vernichtet', 'was']
```

This should have been the following. I missed the points raised in the first comment.

```
>>> import re
>>> sentences = ['1. Glücklicherweise kann der Mensch nur einen gewissen Grad des Unglücks fassen; was darüber hinausgeht, vernichtet ihn oder läßt ihn gleichgültig.', '2. Unter allem Diebesgesindel sind die Narren die schlimmsten. Sie rauben euch beides, Zeit und Stimmung.']
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> sorted(set(re.sub(r'[0-9]', ' ', re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', reduce(lambda x, y: x+' '+y, sentences))).split()), key=str.lower)
['allem', 'beides', 'darüber', 'der', 'des', 'die', 'Diebesgesindel', 'einen', 'euch', 'fassen', 'gewissen', 'gleichgültig', 'Glücklicherweise', 'Grad', 'hinausgeht', 'ihn', 'kann', 'läßt', 'Mensch', 'Narren', 'nur', 'oder', 'rauben', 'schlimmsten', 'Sie', 'sind', 'Stimmung', 'und', 'Unglücks', 'Unter', 'vernichtet', 'was', 'Zeit']
```

Comment: That takes a single string as input, rather than a list of strings, and it leaves in digits.

Comment: @Acccumulation: You're right of course. I think what I've offered is correct now.

Comment: You're very welcome.